# Console returns the whole array but returning "undefined" when I want the first element of it

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I think the screenshot below explains my problem well.  Console is returning the whole array successfully.  But when I want the first element of it, it returns "undefined".
I am pasting the .ts file's related part below as well.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you able to log a `JSON.stringify` version and add the output to this post?

Comment: you should put all the code you need the "response" **into** subscribe function. An observable is async function. "this.chartserice.getAnnualChartBudget(..).subscribe" only "make a call", not wait to get the response

Comment: This is definitely an asynchronous issue. @Eliseo you should post your comment as an answer, it looks like it's the solution :)

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post code and relevant data as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You console debugging code `console.log(..)` statements have executed first before the subscription results are returned. Even though this will give the array output, the first element of the array is showing as `undefined` since an element is being pushed into the array from the service response while the console method is reading the array element.

In your call to the service that is subscribed, move the console logging into the subscription response block as shown:

```
myArrayData: any[] = whatever your array value is

...

this.api.MyServiceMethod().subscribe((response: any) =>
{
    this.myArrayData.push(..response.data);

    console.log("myArrayData = " + this.myArrayData);
    console.log("myArrayData[0] = " + this.myArrayData[0]);
});
```